# Sorting order for an indexed bitfield

Tags: mysql, sorting, innodb

I am using a bitfield which can only have value `1` or `0`. I want to index this field. The rows that will have the value set to `1` will be probably less than 5% of the data.

Am I assuming correctly that the index should be sorted in descending order or does `mySQL` know which way to traverse an index for maximum performance?

PS: I am using `innoDB` as engine.

Answer (score 0):

It usually does not make sense to have an index on a column that only takes on two values.  The reason?  Well, the major benefit of an index is to limit the number of data pages being read for a query.  However, with two values, it is likely that *every* data page is going to have some record with a 0 and some record with a 1.  Hence, the index is not particularly useful.

There are two caveats to this.  First, a binary (boolean) column is reasonable in a multi-column index.  This can be important, for instance, for satisfying `where` clauses that refer to the column.

Second, if the index is *clustered*, then all the 0s are stored together and all the 1s are stored together.  Then -- to a close approximation -- only 5% of the rows would need to be read to handle queries restricted to the rarer value.  Do note, however, that this incurs a bigger overhead on *updating* the value, because changing the value means actually deleting one record on a data page and inserting another record on a different page.